# undefined method `gravatar_for' within edit registration path for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, gravatar

I have a failing rspec test that I can't seem to figure out what could be wrong.  The method is clearly defined, and it works on the site itself; just is failing the test(s).

```
 UserPages edit with invalid information
 Failure/Error: visit edit_user_registration_path(user)
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `gravatar_for'  for_app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb
 # ./app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:8:in
 `_app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the rspec test:

```
    describe "edit" do
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    before do
        sign_in user
        visit edit_user_registration_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do


        it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile")}
        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user")}
        it { should have_link('change', href: "http://gravatar.com/emails")}
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Save changes"}
        it { should have_content('error')}
```

Here is the actual method:

```
 module UsersHelper
#Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50})
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
    end
```

And lastly the code within the view itself:

```
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank">change avatar</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is defined in the `UsersHelper`, however your view is for `Devise::Registration`. So you should move to the proper helper, to the application helper, or create a class with shared `User` and `Devise::Registration` methods and include in both helpers.